# Linux Networking Kernel

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I am reading Kernel Networking In linux. I found this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-networking-stack/ article helpful. After reading this I have a doubt that If I create any software in Linux platform.. Lets say, some chat Program.. Do I have to make use of all those API`s(sk_buff and all) available to connect to the another network? Please help me with it.

Answer (score 3):

sk_buff is a kernel structure that is part of the kernel's TCP/IP stack. You shouldn't need to touch this directly and will in actuality find it difficult to do so.

What you need instead is to learn the user-space API's for network communication. For quickly learning the basics of network communication on Unix, it's tough to beat [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Please tell me in what circumstances we have to use sk_buff or other networking kernel classes.. That`ll make me understand the concept well..

Comment: @Ashwin If you're doing kernel-level work on the TCP/IP stack, then you'll need to use this. That's the simplest way I can think of to explain it, as it encompasses an awful lot. I'd say that the vast, _vast_, _VAST_ majority of network code written for Linux by programmers has no need of this. You should be coding to the POSIX standard, not what's in the kernel.

Comment: @Ashwin Do you understand the difference between user-space and kernel-space?

Comment: Sorry.. I am really new to Linux Kernal. Now understanding the difference those two. But If i have one example where we have to use Networking Kernel(existing one too)..It helps me in understanding the concept.. :(

Comment: @Ashwin I think you're wrong, actually. If you understand the difference between programming in kernel-space vs. user-space, then it will become clear to you that for the purposes of coding a chat program, you should pretend that you never saw a link about the kernel's TCP/IP implementation. Your problem is that you don't know when to program in user-space or kernel-space. It has nothing to do with your understanding TCP/IP networking.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you and thank you very much for answering.. I will search and try to learn it properly.. Suggest me any Tutorials if u have..

Comment: Maybe checkout this: http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a chat software I would recommend to you to checkout the BSD Sockets or any TCP/IP Network Guide for Linux. You don't need to understand what's going on within the Kernel in order to Program a chat software.

The sk_buff is relevant if you would like to create a new device driver but you seem to be above the protocol level.

If you want to create a chat you would create a Server Socket (Listener) and Clients which connect to the address where your Server is listening and exchange information through TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1):

sk_buff is a kernel data structure for socket buffer. You do not have to touch it for your chat server. If you have taken an OS class you must have noticed there is a process structure(struct proc in Linux) but does it mean you have to use it when you write a program ? No. sk_buff is a similar case, Linux kernel uses it to buffer certain data. You don't have to be concerned with it.

For your chat server have a look at Beej's guide, it has an implementation of Chat Server if I am not wrong and its the best guide that I know to get started with Network Programming on Linux, and is filled with humour. For a deeper understanding of Network Programming look at Richard Stevens Unix Network Programming, Volume 1 and Volume 2. It is considered the bible of Network Programming.